# International space station camera views

Tags: iss

Why are the cameras no longer switching views? They have been stuck on down view for several weeks.

Comment: "THE cameras" Not everybody may be familiar with them. Can you include a link?

Comment: The  live ISS HD camera outputs can be viewed on http://www.nasa.gov/multimedia/nasatv/index.html#iss

Comment: Checked again today 25th.March looks like the problem has been rectified different camera views now.